# c++ need to refresh variable

Tags: c++, arrays, flush

I'm creating a program that compares two arrays; the first array, user inputs 5 integers. the second array, the computer selects 5 numbers at random (between 0 & 9 for both arrays).

I need to compare the elements of each array to see if they match. if they match, i add 1 to a counter variable.

( for example user inputs 0 2 2 9 6, computer [ using rand ] picks 2 3 2 9 0.  elemnts 3 & 4 match, so thats two.  now each match has a different scenario )

My problem: the user also inputs how many times they want to compare these arrays (it's a game called pick 5 ).  **I need the counter to reset to zero each time it loops**  I tried using the flush command, but it didn't work.

any ideas?

```
int main ()
{
string name;
float total_amt, bet_amt, win_amt;
int play_amt, user_choice[5] = { }, com_choice[6], i, total=0;
int size = 5;

srand((unsigned)time(0));

cout<<"Welcome to pick 5, where the odds are never in your favor!"<<endl;
cout<<"What is your name?"<<endl;
cin>>name;
cout<<"How much money do you have?"<<endl;
cin>>total_amt;
cout<<"How much money would you like to bet?"<<endl;
cin>>bet_amt;
cout<<"How many times would you like to play?"<<endl;
cin>>play_amt;

for (i=0;i<play_amt;i++)
{ 
    cout<<"Pick 5 integers between 0 & 9 "<<endl;

    cin>>user_choice[0];
    cin>>user_choice[1];
    cin>>user_choice[2];
    cin>>user_choice[3];
    cin>>user_choice[4];

    com_choice[0] = (rand()%9);
    com_choice[1] = (rand()%9);
    com_choice[2] = (rand()%9);
    com_choice[3] = (rand()%9);
    com_choice[4] = (rand()%9);

    cout<<com_choice[0];
    cout<<com_choice[1];
    cout<<com_choice[2];
    cout<<com_choice[3];
    cout<<com_choice[4];



    if (user_choice[0]==com_choice[0])
    {
        total++;
    }
    if (user_choice[1]==com_choice[1])
    {
        total++;
    }
    if (user_choice[2]==com_choice[2])
    {
        total++;
    }
    if (user_choice[3]==com_choice[3])
    {
        total++;
    }
    if (user_choice[4]==com_choice[4])
    {
        total++;
    }

    cout<<"User matched "<<total<<"times"<<endl;


    // scenarios
    if (total>=0 &&total<3)
    {
        total_amt-=bet_amt;
        cout<<"Less than 3 of your numbers matched, tough luck"<<endl;
        cout<<"You now have $"<<total_amt<<"dollars left."<<endl;
    }
        else if (total == 3)
        {
            cout<<"You matched 3 and broke even"<<endl;
        }
        else if( total == 4)
        {
            win_amt = bet_amt*2;
            total_amt = total_amt + (win_amt - bet_amt);
            cout<<"Congrats! you matched 4!!"<<endl;
            cout<<"You now have $"<<total_amt<<"dollars!"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            win_amt = bet_amt*5;
            total_amt = total_amt + (win_amt - bet_amt);
            cout<<"WINNER WINNER YOU MATCHED 5!!"<<endl;
            cout<<"You now have $"<<total_amt<<"dollars!"<<endl;
        }
     // end nested if-else

}  // end for loop

} // end main
```

Comment: Not sure I totally understand, there is no variable called, "counter."  Don't you just want to set total=0; in the start of your "for" loop?

Comment: As the answer says, moving the variable is the good way. If you find yourself in a situation where you need to reset something for a good reason, `var = {};` usually does it nicely.

Comment: sorry my counter variable is "total"

I fixed it by declaring a new total variable within the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to "pre-declare" all variables at the start of function.

If you want the variables to "reset", move the variable declarations to where you're using them, inside the loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<play_amt;i++)
{
    int total = 0; // A new variable 'total', that starts at 0 each time through the loop.
```

Comment: @user2480658, It's good etiquette and important for the site to work well to accept the answer that best solves your problem.

Comment: To do that do i click the green check mark to the left of your response?

Answer (score 1):

You should get into the habit of *delegating* tasks to functions. You are having a problem with `total` because your `main()` function is so long it's hard to keep track of what's happening to that variable. You'll have less trouble if your `for` loop looks like this:

```
for (i=0;i<play_amt;i++)
{
  read_choices(user_choice);
  choose_random(com_coice);
  display_choice(com_choice);

  total = count_matches();
  cout<<"User matched "<<total<<"times"<<endl;

  total_amt += evaluate_scenario(total, bet_amt);
}  // end for loop
```

Comment: i first wanted to get the program running the way i want it to(correct logic. I still want to, like you said, delegate these tasks to their own functions, then i want to put all of this in a class.